# HTML 5 browser's pop-up on input with type="email"

Tags: html, input

When you submit a form in newer browser version that supports HTML5 markup and your form has  `input type="email"` with invalid email address value the form will not be submitted which is good. Also you will get a bubble alert that says `"Please enter an email address"`

A simple [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/SZmWg/4/).

Well, this is nice in some point. In the demo you will see that the pop-up hides my defined error. Is there a way to prevent the bubble to appear? or can i override the style of the bubble?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can stop the browser's build-in validation with the attribute `novalidate`:

```
<form action="" novalidate></form>
```

or you can change the content of the overlay with this JavaScript-property and your own error message:

```
var element = [selector that selects the input field];
element.setCustomValidity('This is not a valid e-mail');
```

But I think you can't style this browser-element yourself.